# Error While Using String LIbrary Function

Tags: c, string, function, error-handling

This is the error that I am facing.

ERROR: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__builtin_strlen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Question Link:[Hackerrank Balanced Brackets](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)

My Code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
char rev(char c){
    char ch;
    if(c=='[')
        ch=']';
    else if(c=='{')
        ch='}';
    else if(c=='(')
        ch=')';

        return ch;
}
int main(){
    int t; //test cases
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        char* s = (char *)malloc(10240 * sizeof(char));
        int l,ret;
        scanf("%s",s);
        l=strlen(s);
        char *st;
        st=(char *)malloc(l * sizeof(char));
        int top=-1;
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
            char ch=s[i];
            char chr=rev(ch);
            ret=strcmp(st[top],chr);
            if(ret!=0){
                top++;
                st[top]=ch;
            }
            else{
                top=top-1;
            }
        }
        if(top==-1)
            printf("YES\n");
        else
            printf("NO\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I shall be really thankful if anybody can help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit: `strcmp` expects a `char*` and you are giving it a `char`; `st[top]` is a `char`.  BTW: your error message doesn't match the code you posted. This is actually a warning and not an error, but IMO this kind of warnings should be considered as an error, because in your case (as in most other cases as well) it's just plain wrong.

Comment: `ret=strcmp(st[top],chr);` what is your purpose with this ?

Comment: `rev` can return a dummy char, use a `switch` instead of if else